# VUE.JS - How to improve performance when loading a static image

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a simple application in Vue.js and I have a component that loads 1 image and 2 texts on the screen, very simple.

However I noticed that every time the image takes a few milliseconds to load than the texts, giving an impression of slowness.

One more piece of information, sometimes it loads quickly and sometimes it takes a while to load. Does this have to do with my machine's performance?

Is there a way for me to optimize this image loading so that it doesn't show the customer this loading?

[image]

```
**Dispenser.vue**
<template>
    <div>
        <gui-action1 :imageName="this.imageName" :title="this.title" :message="this.message" :showLoader="false">
        </gui-action1>
        
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import Action1 from '../../Guidance/Action1.vue'

export default {
    data(){
        return{
            optionSelected: this.$route.params.optionSelected,
            imageName: 'Organization_Image_Interaction_WaitCountReal',
            title: 'Ainda não finalizamos',
            message: 'Aguarde a contagem das notas'
        }
    },
    components: {
        'gui-action1': Action1
    },
    created(){
        setTimeout( () => this.$router.push({ path: "/withdraw/finishing"}), 4000);
    }
}
</script>
<style >
    @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    }
</style>
```

```
**Action.vue (Component)**
<template>
    <div class="guidance">
        <div class="guidance-title" >
            {{title}}
        </div>
        <div class="guidance-image" >
            <img :src="require('../../../static/' +`${imageName}`+ '.svg')">
        </div>
        <div class="guidance-message" >
            {{message}}
        </div>
        <div v-bind:class="{ 'loader': showLoader }" ></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: ['imageName', 'title', 'message', 'showLoader'],

    data(){
        return{
            imageNameDefault: 'Organization_Image_Interaction_WaitCountReal'   
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
        .guidance{
            position: relative;
            top: 70px;
            left: 30px;
        }
        .guidance-image{
            position: relative;
            top:200px;
            left: 220px;
        }

        .guidance-title{
            position: relative;
            top:140px;
            left: -40px;
            font-size: 55px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .guidance-message{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top:650px;
            left: -40px;
            font-size: 55px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .loader {
            border: 7px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
            border-top: 7px solid #386083; /* Blue */
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 130px;
            height: 130px;
            animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
            position: relative;
            left: 518px;
            top: -80px;
            opacity: 60%;
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
            100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Use caching on deployment server and low size images.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan: Is there a way in Vue to delay the loading of the images until all of the text has loaded?

Comment: have an example of how I could do this? @BeshambherChaukhwan

Comment: @RobertHarvey create a question if you need it, comments are not the place for this. At kel, you may have various loading speeds because of cache and general performance of your hardware yeah.

Comment: What happen here?? 

Comment: See there can be multiple scenarios about the component rendering. We all have multiple components in one single looking page and each load/render asynchronously on their own. The final page that the use see can have one parent with many child components or many sibling components.

Comment: Now back to your question. You want your Action.vue to render completely before the user can see it. Meaning that you want the text and image to appear at the same time right? Well the text rendering we can control but the image loading part depends on various factors. It depends on browser, client machine, network speed, image size, and so on. So instead of thinking about the loading time we should focus about its appearance.

Comment: Now we can see the require() in image tag of action vue so its obvious that whenever the value of imageName variable changes, it will load the image and then show it to the user and until the processing of require is not completed, we have loading. So what if I say I move this require part to the parent and provide the already processed data to action vue? Will it help us in any manner?

Comment: Even though it's a static image you need to see that it is in the require() processing and on top of that it is v-bind with img tag meaning there is a binding of that variable with the element and it is registered in vue's change detection cycle. Which I think is a different hierarchy of processing. Makes sense?

Comment: And I'll say it again there can be many ways of improving the performance and it all depends on the requirement. If loading issue is of concerned because of the user experience and not actual app performance then I'll say use some placeholder text or some other placeholder image of few KBs to keep an avatar in place of the real image. So that user will see an avatar of image until the actual image is done loading.

Comment: You can also use things like nextTick(callback) on child which emits events everytime the component is re-rendered. How can that help me? I will simply create my child component with some default data like empty strings for texts and dummy avatar pic for images and keep it hidden as v-show=false until the child component's next tick emits an event. So my child is being rendered in the background but it is hidden on front and a loader is shown until its rendering is completely done. And once its done, I'll rever v-show to true and  viola! U have what u need.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the analysis of my problem and explanation. I will test it the way you suggested and I will also test it the way @kissu suggested, using cloudinary-vue.

Thank you very much, as soon as I have news, I'll come back to that topic to answer the result.

Comment: @bes not sure about your solution, didn't get it really. Also, I don't know how you can make an hook on `image:loaded`, does this kind of hook ever exist? But yeah, setting a lower resolution placeholder is a good idea (pretty much what Cloudinary does). Lastly, please submit your POV into an answer rather in comments here.

Comment: Yes there is no hook on image but there is one Next tick on the entire component for render finish events. Maybe that can be used in this case. But yeah its better to use the low resolution placeholder.

Comment: Rendering a component and an completing loading an image is not bound whatsoever to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [cloudinary-vue](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-vue) for some super simple but performant image loading.

It could allow for some simple image placeholder while loading with only

```html
<cld-image 
  public-id="sample" 
  loading="lazy">
  <cld-placeholder 
    type="vectorize">
  </cld-placeholder>
</cld-image>
```

Here is a Gatsby.js (React) demo but it show pretty clearly how it works with Cloudinary: https://using-gatsby-image.gatsbyjs.org/blur-up/ (click on `Blur up`, `Traced SVG` etc on top of the page).

Ofc, Cloudinary will also resize it to your screen accordingly, may format it into `.webp` or even `.avif` (beta), serve it from a cool CDN and do can do a lot of plenty other stuff. Cannot recommend it enough tbh. Check their documentation and give it a try, it's free so you don't have much to lose.

There is a **LOT** to webperf (too much for a simple answer here), and here is probably one of the best article (redacted each year) about this topic, you will get an exhaustive list of things to implement if you want a blazing fast website: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/01/front-end-performance-2021-free-pdf-checklist/